# Coq: substitution and dependent types

Tags: equality, coq, dependent-type

I am at an odd place trying to prove an equation:

```coq
1 subgoals
A : Type
s : set A
x : A
s0 : s x
x0 : A
s1 : s x0
H : x0 = x
______________________________________(1/1)
stv s x0 s1 = stv s x s0
```

What I want to do is to use `H` to substitute `x` for `x0` everywhere. The rest of the proof would be easy, because I have:

```coq
Definition set (A : Type) := A -> Prop.
Axiom proof_irrelevance: forall (P:Prop) (p1:P) (p2:P), p1 = p2.
```

However, `rewrite H in *` fails, and I cannot rewrite in either `s1` or the conclusion separately.

How should I proceed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`subst x0` did the substitution.